# Не добавляться массив в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не добавляться массив в массив.

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "test"},{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}];
array[0].concat({"form_id": 1});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Потому что элементами массива `array` являются **объекты**, а не массивы. У этих объектов нет метода `concat`.

Comment: Потому что первый элемент **массива** - уже **объект**

Comment: @yar85 push тоже не работает.

Comment: Конечно не работает, потому что метода `push` у объектов тоже нет. Тут уместнее статический метод `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Метод `concat` есть только у массивов, вы же пытаетесь вызвать его с первым элементом массива, который не является массивом.
2. Метод `concat` возвращает новый массив, а не меняет массив, для которого он был вызван, его результат нужно куда-то присваивать.

Из вашего кода не совсем ясно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Если вы хотите добавить поле в первый элемент массива, можно так:

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "test"},{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}];
array[0].form_id = 1;
console.log(array);
```

Или так:

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "test"},{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}];
Object.assign(array[0], {"form_id": 1});
console.log(array);
```

Если вы пытаетесь добавить новый элемент в массив, вашим способом можно так:

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "test"},{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}];
array = array.concat({"form_id": 1});
console.log(array);
```

Но проще так:

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "test"},{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}];
array.push({"form_id": 1});
console.log(array);
```

UPD: Решение прояснённого вопроса:

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "test"},{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}];
array[0].forms = [{"form_id": 1}];
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Мне нужно добавить в первый элемент массива массив {"form_id": 1} что бы получилось так [ {"id": 1, "name": "test", "forms": [{"form_id": 1}]}]

Comment: @Vector, это следовало писать в вoпросе, сразу при его создании.

Comment: @Vector Да, лучше было уточнить, что вы пытаетесь получить. Добавил решение в конец ответа.

Comment: Не могу понять если у меня идет for array[i].forms тогда так не работает

Comment: @Vector Нам ведь трудно гадать, какой у вас код и почему не работает. Создайте новый вопрос или исправьте этот с кодом, воспроизводящим ошибку.